# Как подключиться к SSMS с другого ПК не подключенных к одной сети?

Tags: sql, сервер, express, ssms

Настроил TCP/IP порты и SQL Server на пк2, SSMS с пк1 подключается к пк2, но они подключены к одному Wi-Fi. Как только Wi-Fi отключаю и подключаюсь к интернету с телефона (телефон становится модемом), пк1 не подключается к пк2. Как настроить пк2, чтобы к его SQL Server мог подключаться другой пк, не в ходящий в локальную сеть Wi-Fi? Буду благодарен за подробную инструкцию.